# Django: How to override unique_together error message on Admin Side?

Tags: django, custom-errors

I need some help to customize this error. Seen already on this site how can i change the error for the Model Form. My issue is that i use purely django admin side and i need to change how the error looks. I've added them also in my Class Meta from the admin.py and nothing happen!

[image]

When i put this code to my Class Meta in my models i receive this error message `TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): error_messages`
therefore my question here.

Please find below my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS

class Parcare(models.Model):
    PARKING_PLOT = (('P1', 'Parking #1'), ('P2', 'Parking #2'),('P3', 'Parking #3'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,null=True, default=1, on_delete=True)
    email=models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    parking_on = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,blank=True, null=True,
                                  help_text='Alege data cand doresti sa vii in office',)
    parking_off = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True, 
                                help_text='Alege Data Plecarii')  
    numar_masina = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="IF77WXV",blank=True, null=True, 
                                help_text='Introdu Numarul Masinii')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, default="P1",null=True, choices=PARKING_PLOT,
                                help_text='Alege Locul de Parcare Dorit')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False,blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    venire = models.TimeField(default=time(9, 00), auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False, help_text='Alege Ora Venirii')
    plecare = models.TimeField(default=time(18, 00), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, help_text='Alege Ora Plecarii')
    # booked = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    objects = ParcareManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location + " | " + str(self.parking_on) + " | " + str(self.parking_off)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "parcare"
        ordering = ["-parking_on"]
        unique_together = ("parking_on", "location")
         error_messages = {
             NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                 'unique_together': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique. This means that the same parking plot is already booked during time period!",
             }
         }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you searching to find a way to modify the error message ?

Comment: Yes Abjijith! Thank you! I want to customize a better error message, as the users will have no it background!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you need. The validate_unique function checks for all the uniqueness constraints on your model. Place this function inside your Parcare Model.

```
def validate_unique(self,exclude=None):
        try:
            super(Parcare,self).validate_unique()
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise ValidationError(self.user+"your message")
```

Nb:You can use any field instead of self.user

Answer (score 0):

Define a model form that [overrides the error message](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#considerations-regarding-model-s-error-messages) for `unique_together`:

```
class ParcareForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'unique_together': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique. This means that the same parking plot is already booked during time period!",
            },
        }
```

Then tell your model admin class to us your model form by setting [`form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form):

```
class ParcareAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ParcareForm

admin.register(Parcare, ParcareAdmin)
```

Comment: And i have to put below this form the class Meta?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You said in your question that you already understand how to change the error for a model form.

Comment: Yes, but i havent used a modelform in my code...i have only models and admin. This is why i am asking

Comment: From your question it sounded like you already knew how customise the error message for a model form, so I left out that part. I have now added an example model form to the answer.